# Talking to objects and Avoda Zara

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, avodah-zarah, speech-talking, marit-ayin

This question inspired by [This question here at programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118140/how-can-i-get-the-benefit-of-working-with-a-co-worker-if-i-have-no-co-workers)

There is a concept in some programing circles called ["Rubber Ducking"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking), where one expresses a problem to a rubber ducky and through that process is able to figure out the answer to their problem.

Is there any problem where with Avoda Zara, or Morit Ayin.. and is there a more Jewish way of doing this?

Comment: AFAIK it works if one speaks his arguments aloud, even not to any object.

Comment: Maybe try setting up a Chevrutah. You may then even get some good answers to you r thoughts which the duck isn't able to supply.

Comment: If someone does this and ends up making a mistake, can you say about him: "לא דק"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once heard Rav Shmuel Kaminetsky describing the life of a certain Rav in a little shtetel many years ago. The people of the village were unlearned, and the Rav, who was a big Talmid Chacham, had no one with whom to converse in Torah learning. What did he do? He would put his hat on the banister next to the Aron Hakodesh, and speak as if there was an attentive listener. After each proposed approach, he would decide how the "listener" might respond, either shaking the hat up and down (affirmative, enthusiastic) or side to side (*nah...*). Apparently this method helped him preserve his scholarship and sanity.

Comment: This is a beautiful story.

Comment: The reason I have not accepted this answer yet, is because it does not directly relate to the aspect of the question I am curious about.. i.e., using the duck to solve a problem. Here the hat is just having a conversation but not necessarily being used to say, answer a shaila.

Comment: Actually, @avi, you did get an answer from a hat... have you noticed my gravatar? :P

Comment: No disrespect, but this was how he *preserved* his sanity?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's a problem. Just don't start asking the duck to help you.

Comment: If you read the link to the initial question, the whole point here is to get help.. so do you mean don't ask to get help, or don't use the phrase "so duck, can you help me?"